# ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U23') dtype('<U23') dtype('<U23')

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

When trying to convert the sklearn dataset into pandas dataframe by the following code I am getting this error "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import numpy as np
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
data = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[cancer['data'], cancer['target']],columns=   cancer['feature_names'] + cancer['target'])
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I converted the sklearn dataset to a pandas dataframe. The target column name needs to be appended.

```
bostonData = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[boston['data'], boston['target']],
                     columns= np.append(boston['feature_names'],['target']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have numpy array of strings please provide full error therefore we figure out what's missing;

For example I am assuming you got dtype('U9'), please add;

`dtype=float` into your array. Something like not certain;

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[cancer['data'], cancer['target']],columns=   cancer['feature_names'] + cancer['target'], dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's just easier to keep it simple.  Create a DF for both data and target, then merge using pandas.

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data=cancer['data'] ,columns=cancer['feature_names'])

target_df = pd.DataFrame(data=cancer['target'], columns=['target']).reset_index(drop=True)

target_df.rename_axis(None)

df = pd.concat([data_df, target_df], axis=1)
```